# Speed up window.onload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am beginner in javascript and Jquery. I have javascript code which generates table of content based on `<h2>` `<h3>` tags. It is slow as it runs when the whole page gets rendered. I tried to replace `window.onload` with `document.onload` but it didn't work. Is there any other way to improve its speed. Reproducible example - https://jsfiddle.net/mja3xpfr/

```
window.onload = function () {
    var toc = "";
    var level = 0;
    var maxLevel = 3;

    document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML =
        document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML.replace(
            /<h([\d]).*>\s*[\d]*\s?[.]?\s?([^<]+)<\/h([\d])>/gi,
            function (str, openLevel, titleText, closeLevel) {

                if (openLevel > maxLevel) {return str;}

                if (openLevel > level) {
                    toc += (new Array(2)).join("<ol>");
                } else if (openLevel < level) {
                    toc += (new Array(level - openLevel + 1)).join("</ol>");
                }

                level = parseInt(openLevel);

                var anchor = titleText.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]+/g, "-");

                toc += "<li><a href=\"#" + anchor + "\">" + titleText
                    + "</a></li>";

                return "<a name=\"" + anchor + "\">"
                    + "<h" + openLevel + " style=\"padding-top: 60px; margin-top: -60px;\">"+ str + "</h" + closeLevel + ">" +"</a>";
            }
        );

    if (level) {
        toc += (new Array(level + 1)).join("</ol>");
    }

    document.getElementById("toc").innerHTML += toc;
};
```

Comment: If you are using jQuery the place all of your code inside `$(document).ready()` function. or if you are using javascript then use self executing function like `(function(){ //place your code here...  })`

Comment: It's not the load handler per se that slows down loading. I think the regex-replacement is the bottleneck here. You may want to try to use real DOM-scripting here (loop `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(/*css selector*/))` and replace all elements with `document.createElement("li") /* ... etc */`)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to use DOM-scripting to create a TOC (so, no string manipulation). It may not be exactly what you need, but ofcourse you can [fiddle with it](https://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/p2o6fmtq/) as much as you want.

This should work a lot faster. Furthermore, if your `javascript` tag is near the bottom of you html (right before the closing `</body>`-tag, you don't really need a load handler.

```js
(() => {
  const headers = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("h1, h2, h3, h4"));
  const maxLevel = 4;
  let tocLis = [];

  for(let header of  headers) {
    const level = parseInt(header.nodeName.replace(/[^\d]/g, ""));
      if (level < maxLevel) {
        
        // 1. create and insert anchor
        let anchor = document.createElement("a");
        anchor.name = header.textContent;
        header.parentNode.insertBefore(anchor, header);
        
        // 2. create and add a list item
        let li = document.createElement("li");
        let liRef = document.createElement("a");
        liRef.href = `#${header.textContent}`;
        liRef.textContent = header.textContent;
        li.appendChild(liRef);
        tocLis.push(li);
    }
    
    // 3. if list items were created, add them to #toc
    if (tocLis.length) {
      const ul = document.createElement("ul");
      tocLis.forEach( el => ul.appendChild(el));
      document.querySelector("#toc").appendChild(ul);
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<div id="toc">
  <span>Table of Contents</span>
</div>

<hr />

<div id="contents">
  <h2>Apple</h2>
  adsdasdsa  
  
  <h2>Orange</h2>
  adsdasd
</div>

<!--to check if anchors work -->
<div style="height:2000px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

`$..event.add(window, 'load', () => {
    //your code to run here
});`

Though using pure javascript is still the fastest option

Comment: How would this be faster?

Comment: Its meant to be `$.event` also I am saying running **pure javascript** is the fastest option

Comment: Its runs @ window level

Answer (score 0):

window.onload occurs after all stuff (images, texts, etc) are loaded.
Instead of using window.load, you can use [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event which is used by jQuery's $(document).ready().

So, to make it faster, you can change your code as follows:

```
$(function() {
...
});
```

$ makes your function to run when DOM content gets loaded. It's the same as

```
$(document).ready(function() { ... })
```